# Rad Grid not binding with response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, rad

I have a page grid.aspx which contains a rad grid, when a row is selected for update the user is redirected to another page where the he can update the row, after submitting the updates I want to redirect the user back to grid.aspx, but the grid displays that there are no records to display?
When I navigate to another page and then go back to grid.aspx it works fine.

FYI: the update page doesn't use a data source, the item is retrieved and the form is filled manually. I used response.redirect("grid.aspx").

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is your grid.aspx page the victim of caching? To eliminate this, add a random parameter to the query string:

```
Response.Redirect("grid.aspx?z=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Maybe you have not bound your grid or fetched your data during the correct part of the page lifecycle. If you fetch your data and always bind it (irrespective of IsPostback) in the Page_Load, does that fix the issue? If it does then start with that, and then step by step change when/how you bind until you are satisfied with the result.

Of course it could also just be a bug in your code, which no-one can solve without seeing your code.

Comment: How can I tell if the cache is causing the problem? I tried both of your proposed solutions but they didn't work for me

Comment: The first suggestion will avoid caching, so if it doesn't work then that is not your problem. I guess we are left with the third option - a bug in your code?